# Return to main actuality after open activity B from notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, broadcastreceiver

code create notification from BroadcastReceiver

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(G.context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(G.context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("text")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(Color.MAGENTA);

        Intent intent = new Intent(G.context, B.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(G.context);
        taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) G.context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(2, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently in `MainActivity.java` and then click on notification and go to `B Activity` the just simply call `this.finish()` or `onBackPressed()` in your back press control `onClick()` method. If your are opening your `B Activity` from any where by clicking one notification then Call below method in your `B activity`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

> Other way you can do like this

You Dont need do anything. By default when you move from Activity A to Activity B, Android adds the Activity A to the backstack. When you press the back button from Activity B or finish it, it automatically restore the Activity A from backstack.

If you wish to finish your Activity B programmatically call activity's finish() method when you want to do it.

For more detail [Check this](http://You%20Dont%20need%20do%20anything.%20Just%20remove%20your%20onBackPressed()%20method%20from%20Activity%20B.%20%20By%20default%20when%20you%20move%20from%20Activity%20A%20to%20Activity%20B,%20Android%20adds%20the%20Activity%20A%20to%20the%20backstack.%20When%20you%20press%20the%20back%20button%20from%20Activity%20B%20or%20finish%20it,%20it%20automatically%20restore%20the%20Activity%20A%20from%20backstack.%20%20If%20you%20wish%20to%20finish%20your%20Activity%20B%20programmatically%20call%20activity's%20finish()%20method%20when%20you%20want%20to%20do%20it.)

Comment: Thank
With this method, when I open the B activity from app and put the back key button, the new created activity main That's not right. I think

Comment: its possible by call just simple `onBackPressed()` method also or `this.finish()` also but if no any previous activity stack is available then app will be closed

Comment: This should not happen when we call the B active program
That is, you should not create an instance from the main activity one
Is there another way?